# Failed to load Tensorboard

Tags: machine-learning, anaconda, tensorboard, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

ERROR: Failed to launch TensorBoard (exited with 1).
Contents of stderr:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arshad/anaconda3/bin/tensorboard", line 10, in 
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "/home/arshad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 58, in run_main
    default.get_plugins() + default.get_dynamic_plugins(),
  File "/home/arshad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 110, in get_dynamic_plugins
    for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins')
  File "/home/arshad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/default.py", line 110, in 
    for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins')
  File "/home/arshad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2442, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/arshad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2465, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "/home/arshad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 791, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (grpcio 1.16.1 (/home/arshad/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('grpcio>=1.24.3'))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case it still doesn't work for you, what you need to do is upgrade your grpcio package with:

```
pip install --upgrade grpcio
```

It should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, you have to activate the environment where tensorflow is installed using the below commands

```
conda activate <environment_name>   or source activate <environment_name>
```

then, run below tensorboard command by passing log_dir as parameter.

```
  tensorboard --log_dir <log directory name>
```

For more details, run

```
tensorboard -help
```