# I am Unable to Load Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to check how my training model is doing via Tensorboard by using **tensorboard --logdir=training**, But I am getting this error message.

I have tried to uninstall and install **'grpcio>=1.24.3'** , but is still not  working. I also tried to implement  a [stackoverflow soln on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737443/failed-to-load-tensorboard)

```
2020-03-30 18:05:59.674074: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not 
load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-03-30 18:06:00.684485: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart 
dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\8470p\Anaconda3\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 59, in run_main
default.get_plugins() + default.get_dynamic_plugins(),
File "c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 115, in 
get_dynamic_plugins
for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins')
File "c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 115, in <listcomp>
for entry_point in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('tensorboard_plugins')
File "c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2445, in load
self.require(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2468, in require
items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
File "c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (grpcio 1.16.1 (c:\users\8470p\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), 
Requirement.parse('grpcio>=1.24.3'))
```

Comment: `conda update -c anaconda grpcio`?

Comment: @hoefling I am still having the same error response after running this `conda update -c anaconda grpcio`